# Show category name with link

Tags: category-products, magento2.2.0

It is code to show category name in product listing.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();
}
?>
```

How would I get a category with a link?

Comment: Try this `$cat->getUrl()`

Comment: @Dinesh thanks. can get link with $cat->getUrl().

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
    echo $category->getUrl();
?>
```

Comment: <code>
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    
  
    echo "<br/>";
   
    echo "<a href='".$cat->getUrl()."' class='".$cat->getId()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a>";
    
    }
</code>

Comment: Did you try my code ????????

Comment: yes. not working well.

Comment: Not working well meaning

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Meetanshi\HelloWorld\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
class Meetanshi
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $categoryRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        .........
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

     public  function getCategory()
    {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        return $category->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Call this block from listing page by passing category id like below

```
$block->getCategory('YOUR_CATEGORY_ID');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get category Data:

1) Using Object Manager:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentCategory = $registry->registry('current_category');
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() ;
```

2) Or using Block

i) Create Block:

```
app/code/Allin/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

<?php
namespace Allin\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
?>
```

ii) Get current category in any template (.phtml) file

```
// print current category data
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() . '<br />';
```